# How should I open the package "scater"?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have the lastest update of [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) (`3.5.2`), but if I want to install the package it would give me an error. What should I do?

```
install.packages("scater")
library(scater, quietly = TRUE)
```

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Mary/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) Warning in install.packages :   package
>   ‘scater’ is not available (for R version 3.5.2)

Answer (score 1):

From the package Readme file on github. You should install by BiocManager

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly=TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("scater")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried it here, and it's currently installing (I'm using the pacman package btw, but I imagine it works the same if you use install.packages instead of p_load)

```
pacman::p_load(BiocManager, scater)
```

Edit : I'm running R Studio (3.5.0), but I had the same message as you did when I tried to run your code.